# Get unique values

Tags: powershell

We're trying to optimize some code that removes duplicates from an `Array` as fast as possible. Normally this can be easily done by piping the input to `Group-Object` and then using only the `Name` property. But we would like to avoid the pipeline, as it is slower.

However, we tried the following code:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$uniqueFrom = @() 

$From = @('A', 'A', 'B')

$From.Where({-not ($uniqueFrom.Contains($_))}).ForEach({
    $uniqueFrom.Add($_)
})

$uniqueFrom
```

In theory, this should work. But for one reason or another the output is not the expected `@('A', 'B')`. Why is it not reevaluating the `ArrayList` in the `.where` clause?

Comment: Why so complicated? `$uniqueFrom = @($From | Select-Object -Unique)`

Comment: Because piping is slower and I wanted to try the new techniques described [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/).

Comment: _"Because piping is slower"_  Is it even noticeable?  While technically, it might be, in many cases any speed improvement from refactoring is either not noticed by users (e.g. when the script runs unattended), or is swamped by other factors (e.g. network latency).  So, unless you are certain there is an excessive delay, it is probably better to stick with standard PowerShell techniques, so your code is easier to understand/maintain.

Comment: Thx @boxdog for your opinion. If possible, stick to the defaults as much as possible. I totally agree! In this case I just wanted to know why this isn't working and see if there's a speed difference with the regular approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience reducing the 'pipe filtering' to get the unique values can be achieve by using `DataView`. If you are processing an array you need to convert this to a `DataTable` first before you get the values using the `DataView`.

e.g.

```
$arr = @('val1','val1','val1','val2','val1','val3'....)

$newDatatable = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
[void]$newDatatable.Columns.Add("FetchUniqueColumn")

foreach($e in $arr)
{
    $row = $newDatatable.NewRow()
    $row.Item('FetchUniqueColumn') = $e
    $newDatatable.Rows.Add($row)
}

$filterDataView     = New-Object System.Data.Dataview($newDatatable)
$UniqueDT           = $filterDataView.ToTable($true,'FetchUniqueColumn')
$UniqueValues_array = $UniqueDT.Rows.FetchUniqueColumn
```

Note this is a whole lot faster if your input is a `DataTable` since you don't have to convert it anymore prior to setting the `DataView` filter for unique values to `$true` in creating the `$UniqueDT` datatable from the dataview:

```
$UniqueDT = $filterDataView.ToTable($true,'FetchUniqueColumn')
```

Tested by querying 1 column with 3000 rows datatable from SQL.
My results are as follows:

```
**With 1 column Data Table as input
  Select -Unique - 300 ms 
  Using DataView - 21 ms

**With @() array as input (converted SQL results to array prior to benchmarking)
  Select Unique  - 262 ms
  Using DataView - 106 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

---

***Disclaimer**: in this answer I'm just explaining why the current code isn't working, not attempting to give alternative solution. For solution check [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556112/9902555).*

---

> Why is it not reevaluating the ArrayList in the .where clause?

It's not supposed to do this. What it is actually doing is filtering here:

```
$From.Where({-not ($uniqueFrom.Contains($_))})
```

and then executing

```
$uniqueFrom.Add($_)
```

for each element. As you did

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$uniqueFrom = @()
```

this array is empty and therefore will return `$false` for any `$uniqueFrom.Contains($_)`

---

#### Proof:

To verify that what I've written above is true you can do the following:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$uniqueFrom = @()
$uniqueFrom.add("A")
$From.Where({-not ($uniqueFrom.Contains($_))}).ForEach({
    $uniqueFrom.Add($_)
})
```

Output is `A, B` (`A` was added manually, two `A` were skipped as this entry already exists in `$uniqueFrom`, `B` was added inside `ForEach`) as expected.

Comment: Thx, this explains it. I was under the impression that each element passing the `.where` filter would immediately be added to the `$uniqueFrom` ArrayList. But this doesn't seem to be the case.